# UnicodeDecodeError reading a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Below is part of my code that is giving me error..

```
# get all browser products
raw_json_file = open( script_dir + "raw_json.js", 'r' )
raw_json = raw_json_file.read()
all_str = raw_json[ raw_json.find("{"): ]
all_obj = json.loads(all_str)
browser_products = all_obj["categories"]["6"]["products"]
```

the error I am getting here is as below:

```
C:\Python34>python parse.py 8.3.4
argument is 8.3.4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse.py", line 42, in <module>
    raw_json = raw_json_file.read()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 563011: character maps to <undefined>
```

Please let me know how to solve this error.

Comment: have you created your JSON using the correct mapping. JSON <==> Python, like this.
object == dict, 
array == list,
string == unicode,
number (int) == int long,
number (real) == float,
true == True,
false == False,
null == None.

Comment: `js` files are javascript. `json` is a json file.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `open()` in Python 3, by default it will assume the file is encoded in some system default which, it appears in your case, is the *Windows `cp1252`* encoding. Perhaps the file is in fact encoded in some other way, for example the very common *`UTF-8`*.
You can try

```
raw_json_file = open( script_dir + "raw_json.js", 'r', encoding='utf8' )
```

to see if that is so, but really you need to ask whoever provided the file what encoding they used.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is try encoding and decoding to `utf-8`.

```
# get all browser products
raw_json_file = open( script_dir + "raw_json.js", 'r' )
raw_json = bytes(raw_json_file.read()).decode()
all_str = raw_json[ raw_json.find("{"): ]
all_obj = json.loads(all_str)
browser_products = all_obj["categories"]["6"]["products"]
#Do this to the strings you get from the JSON file directly. Then, use them as needed.
```

Computers have different codes and values they can give to certain characters, one of these codesets is `unicode`. However, these aren't normal strings so you have to convert them in Python before using them. Try seeing [This Article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) for more information.

Also, your file is not a JSON file but a JavaScript programming language file used for developing websites. Please confirm the validity of your file if you didn't make it. If you made the file yourself, then you don't need to worry. Changing the extension is just a way to tell your computer what program to use to open the file.

## KEEP IN MIND

When I did `decode()`, it automatically decodes from `utf-8` characterization. If you do not know what the encoding of the file is, try installing `chardet` module with pip and see the [chardet documentation](http://chardet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) for usage tutorials. Once you find out (sometimes, if your file uses different character sets, chardet will not work and you will have to change all the encodings to one uniform encoding) the encoding, add it as a string argument to `decode()`.

Sorry if this all seems overwhelming, but there are a lot of people who have had this error. Just google it and find the solution :).